# How to create a View from a Strongly Typed ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I began using ViewModels to create custom views that represent several underlying EF entities in MVC4. I created a folder named 'ViewModels' in my MVC project and have my classes within that folder. What I want to do is create a *new* view based on the strongly typed ViewModel class. However the wizzard displayed when creating a View in ASP.NET MVC with the **"Create a strongly-typed view"** option and subsequent **"Model Class"** dropdown selection *does not* contain my ViewModel class. The only classes listed are those from my Entity Framework model.

How do I create a View based on my created ViewModel class or rather get it to show in that list of Model classes?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to compile the MVC project before the new ViewModel class will show up in that dropdown.

Comment: @JohnW - You are 100% right. Not typical of me to get that hyper to try something without re-building. You suggestion is not a comment but really the answer. Re-post as the answer and I will mark it so. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile the MVC project before the new ViewModel class will show up in that dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Bu default, the Wizard will show all `Class file` names except those Controller files (which ends with  `Controller.cs`)in the Model DropDown

Simply create a new normal View and then add this as the first line of the view file

```
@model YourViewModelClassName
```

Assuming `YourViewModelClassName` is the name of your class you created for ViewModel.

ex : If you have a Customer View Model like this

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
```

So the view should be like this

```
@model CustomerViewModel
<p>Your view content can go here</p>
```

If your class ViewModel class resides in a a namespace, you need to specify the fully qualified class name

```
@model MyNameSpaceName.CustomerViewModel
```

Assuming `MyNameSpaceName` is the name of your namespace where this class resides